# generate log for each day

Tags: cmd, vbscript, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to create a log file for day with this script:

```
hostIp      = WScript.Arguments(0)
logfilename = WScript.Arguments(1)
Set fso     = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Shell   = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'OpenTextFile Method requires a Const value
'(Over)Write = 2  Append = 8  
d = Day(Now) 
m = Month(Now)  
y = Year(Now)
myDateFormat= d & "-" & m & "-" & y 
Set logfile = fso.OpenTextFile(logfilename & " " & myDateFormat & ".log", 8, True)
shellstring = "%comspec% /c ping -t -f -l 32 -w 1000 " & hostIP
Set oExec   = Shell.Exec(shellstring)
WScript.Echo "Ping Error log With Timestamp - Ctrl + C to halt"
Do While oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream <> True
    pingline = Date & " " & Time & " " & oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
    'If InStr(pingline, "TTL=") = 0 Then
        logfile.WriteLine(pingline)
    'End If
Loop
```

I thought it was fine but I've run it for 3 days and there is only one file instead of 3. any ideas about whats wrong with the script?
BTW I run this script on CMD with this line:

```
FileName ip logname.log
```

Comment: what's the name of the log file you have?

Comment: PingRemote 12-10-2017.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm... well, yes, your logfile won't magically change just because you will it to. You need to actually tell your code to do that.

Since you're basically running an infinite loop (due to `ping -t`) you need to check the date *inside* the loop and open a new file when the date changes:

```
d = Date - 1
Set logfile = Nothing
Do Until oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    pingline = Date & " " & Time & " " & oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
    If d <> Date Then
        If Not logfile Is Nothing Then logfile.Close
        d = Date
        myDateFormat = Day(d) & "-" & Month(d) & "-" & Year(d)
        Set logfile = fso.OpenTextFile(...)
    End If
    logfile.WriteLine(pingline)
Loop
logfile.Close
```